# Is there any win32 API to replace LoadString for Windows Store app?

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, windows-runtime

I am trying to build `Boost.Regex` on windows store, and facing this issue:

> ......\libs\regex\build..\src\w32_regex_traits.cpp(275) : error
>   C3861: 'LoadStringA': identifier not found
>   ......\libs\regex\build..\src\w32_regex_traits.cpp(308) : error
>   C3861: 'LoadStringW': identifier not found

From MSDN, I found the `LoadString` is banned in Windows Store app. However, I didn't find the replacement win32 API of `LoadString`.

If there is NOT replacement Win32 api for `LoadString`, I have to use the WinRT API(C++/CX). Seems that the `Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResouceLoader` can be used to load string from resource. However, I don't know how to call R`esourceLoader::GetString(String^ resource)` with the existed parameters.

Here is the original code in Boost.Regex. Can anybody tell me how to get the resource key(String) from the `HINSTANCE` and resource `uID`?

```
BOOST_REGEX_DECL std::wstring BOOST_REGEX_CALL w32_cat_get(const cat_type& cat, lcid_type, int i, const std::wstring& def)
{
   wchar_t buf[256];
   if(0 == ::LoadStringW(
      static_cast<HMODULE>(cat.get()),
      i,
      buf,
      256
   ))
   {
      return def;
   }
   return std::wstring(buf);
}
```

Here is the sample code of ResourceLoader:

```
auto loader = ref new Windows::ApplicationModel::Resources::ResourceLoader::GetForCurrentView();
String^ text = loader->GetString("Farewell");
```

And this is the reference of ResourceLoader class in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2

Thanks,
Eason

Comment: You should be able to convert the `String` (actually `Platform::String`) to a `std::wstring` like this: `return std::wstring(text->Data());`

Comment: This is an XY question, you of course don't actually *need* to load strings from resources to use Boost.Regex.  It is part of C++11 today so you could just use the standard C++ version.  Or you could just provide your own stubs for LoadStringA/W to keep the compiler and linker happy.  Or you could submit a patch to Boost to #ifdef these functions out.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, we don't need to load string to user Boost.Regex. However this is function w32_cat_get is an private function which is used internally in Boost.Regex. So I have to make it pass build. What I want to know is how to replace the LoadString with other API.

Comment: Did you get this solved ? I would also be needing the answer.

Comment: @Dr.Jukka, not yet. I gave up build boost on Windows Store.